# Linking C code, error undefined reference

Tags: c, gcc, linker

When I try to compile a c, I get this error:

```
/opt/linux-devkit/bin/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -Wall -g -DVERSION_STR=\"\" -DBUILD_STR=\"\" -DARM=\"1\" -fPIC -pthread -DLINUX -DnotStandAlone -DQT_NO_DEBUG -mstructure-size-boundary=8 -I../3rdParty/uthash -I../3rdParty/cscl -I../3rdParty/include -I../3rdParty/include/libxml -I../sculib/include -I../include -Iinclude -L../arm/debug/lib/ -L../3rdParty/lib/ -lsculib -lsqlite3 Test/src/test_profile_missing.c ./bin/arm/debug/database.o ./bin/arm/debug/messageProcessor.o -o ../arm/debug/bin/test_profile_missing

Test/src/test_profile_missing.c: In function 'main':
Test/src/test_profile_missing.c:120:28: warning: unused variable 'sMessage'
./bin/arm/debug/database.o: In function `scuDbStoreMeterRegistration':
src/database.c:404: undefined reference to `sPtrMetermap'

./bin/arm/debug/messageProcessor.o: In function `processDataMsgReqThread':
src/messageProcessor.c:159: undefined reference to `scuCoreCleanDataCell'
```

however, when I run:

```
nm -u bin/arm/debug/database.o|grep sPtrMetermap
```

it indicates that database.o has such a reference and the code indicates that the declaration exists. How do I narrow down this problem and make it link?

Comment: You need to add a link to the library containing those symbols (functions) whatever they are, you can google for that or maybe tell what you are compiling.

Comment: thanks, I added one of the object file core.o which was needed. Now, it complains multiple definition of `my_process_ver'. When I comment out the declaration 'my_process_ver', it says error: 'my_process_ver' undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: your definition in the header file probably doesn't match the c file exactly, you can usually just copy it from the c function and add a ";" after the parenthesis

Comment: No. I see the problem. The char array my_process_ver is declared in both core.c and test_profile_missing.c and when I try to link them together, I run into this. But how come adding the "extern" keyword does not solve the problem?

Comment: I got it. I just had to figure out what objects should be included and what objects should not be included to prevent definition overlaps.

Comment: if you figured it out, why don't you post your complete solution as an answer and mark it solved